# Cannot read property '_babelPolyfill' of undefined

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I'm trying to get babel-polyfill working with for a library but I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_babelPolyfill' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/foo/webpack-library-starter/lib/library.js:73:6)
...
```

I'm using [webpack-library-starter](https://github.com/krasimir/webpack-library-starter) as my template.

**Full replication details:**

```
git clone https://github.com/krasimir/webpack-library-starter.git
cd webpack-library-starter
npm i
npm i --save babel-polyfill
```

Tried both adding `import 'babel-polyfill'` to the beginning of "src/index.js" and not having it.

Add `'babel-polyfill'` to "webpack.config.js":

```
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', __dirname + '/src/index.js'],
```

Then build and test:

```
npm run dev
npm run build
npm test
```

Comment: Could you also add `'/src/index.js'` to the question?

Comment: @StefanDragnev You mean the file content? It's all in that repository I've linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This project template is somewhat ill-advised. Webpack creates packages that are meant to be loaded in a browser environment. Mocha, however, runs in node. So you have to take into account what transmogrifications webpack does to the bundled code and what happens when this code is fed back into node.

When `babel-polyfill` is bundled by webpack, there's this implicit assumption that the bundle will be loaded in a browser and some specific globals (namely, that `this` in unbound functions refers to `window`) will be there.

The proper way to load `babel-polyfill` in node is with node's own `require`. For example, change the test script in `package.json` to:

`"test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --colors -r babel-polyfill ./test/*.spec.js"`

Your library's bundle should not load `babel-polyfill` at all though. If your library initializes `babel-polyfill` and someone includes your library into their project which also initializes `babel-polyfill`, they'll get an exception stating, quote, `"only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed"`.

Comment: "Your library's bundle should not load babel-polyfill at all though. ..." A very important point that I completely missed! Thank you very much.